# Postgresql: fetch all not showing any data

Tags: postgresql, cursor

Data is not showing when I tried to fetch data from cursor. dbo.show_cities_multiple2 is procedure which returns two cursors.

```
    

    DO $$ 
    <<first_block>>
    DECLARE
        counter refcursor := 0;
        ca_cur refcursor:=null;
        tx_cur refcursor:=null;
    BEGIN 
        call dbo.show_cities_multiple2(ca_cur, tx_cur);
        EXECUTE 'FETCH ALL from "' || tx_cur || '"';
        RAISE NOTICE 'The current value of counter is %', ca_cur;
    END first_block $$;
```

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dbo.show_cities_multiple2(inout ref1 refcursor, inout ref2 refcursor) 
    AS 
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
        OPEN ref1 FOR SELECT city, state FROM cities WHERE state ='CA';   
        OPEN ref2 FOR SELECT city, state FROM cities WHERE state ='TX';   
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: Add code in comment to question in properly formatted style. Since a procedure can't return anything I don't see how this is going to work. See [plpgsql cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING)  *43.7.3.5. Returning Cursors* for how to do this with functions.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver procedure is returning two cursors with inout  parameter type. Procedure codeis mentioned in first comment.

Comment: No it is not. Read [Returning from a procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-PROCEDURE): "A procedure does not have a return value.". Use functions if you want to do this.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver while a procedure does not have a return value per se a procedure does populate (return) `out` and `inout` variables. In your reference "If the procedure has output parameters, the final values of the output parameter variables will be returned to the caller". Also see the section "Calling a Procedure" immediately following and the example there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you aren't actually doing anything with the results of your `EXECUTE FETCH ...` `EXECUTE` merely runs the statement that comes after it. A plpgsql function does not [return](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) anything unless you explicitly specify `RETURN ...`,`RETURN NEXT ...` or `RETURN QUERY ...`. Furthermore, an anonymous `DO $$` block cannot return any results. So if you want to actually retrieve rows from the cursor, you need to name your cursors and execute your fetch outside of the do block:

```sql
  DO $$ 
    <<first_block>>
    DECLARE
        counter integer := 0;
        ca_cur refcursor:='ca_cur'; --name your cursors first, otherwise they will be anonymous!
        tx_cur refcursor:='tx_cur';
    BEGIN 
        call dbo.show_cities_multiple2(ca_cur, tx_cur);
        ...
    END first_block $$;
--Fetch
FETCH ALL FROM tx_cur;
```

Alternatively, you can define a standard function and use `RETURN NEXT` OR `RETURN QUERY` to return the result sets from the cursors:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION return_city_data() RETURNS SETOF cities AS $$
    DECLARE
        counter integer = 0;
        tx_cur refcursor = 'tx_cur';
        ca_cur refcursor = 'ca_cur';
        rec RECORD;

    BEGIN

        CALL dbo.show_cities_multiple(tx_cur,ca_cur);

        -- Iterate over each record in the cursor
        FOR rec in EXECUTE 'FETCH ALL FROM ' || tx_cur  LOOP
            counter = counter + 1;
            -- RETURN NEXT means "Append each value to the function's result set".
            RETURN NEXT rec;
        END LOOP;

        FOR rec in EXECUTE 'FETCH ALL FROM ' || ca_cur  LOOP
            counter = counter + 1;
            RETURN NEXT rec;
        END LOOP;

        --All records have been appended to the result set. the cursors can now be closed.
        CLOSE tx_cur;
        CLOSE ca_cur;

        RAISE NOTICE 'The current value of counter is %', "counter";

    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

OR

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION return_city_data() RETURNS SETOF cities AS $$
DECLARE
    counter integer = 0;
    tx_cur refcursor = 'tx_cur';
    ca_cur refcursor = 'ca_cur';
    rec RECORD;

BEGIN

    CALL dbo.show_cities_multiple(tx_cur,ca_cur);
    -- RETURN QUERY means "append all rows from the query to the function's result set"
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'FETCH ALL FROM ' || tx_cur;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'FETCH ALL FROM ' || ca_cur;

    CLOSE tx_cur;
    CLOSE ca_cur;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can use either of these forms with a simple `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM return_city_data();
```

Note that unlike `RETURN`, `RETURN NEXT` and `RETURN QUERY` do not terminate your function and you can use them multiple times in your blocks. The function will then naturally terminate at the end of the last block.